# I messed up a "While" loop... Can i fix it?

Tags: c#, file, while-loop

I tryed to make a while loop, and i know the problem, i just have no idea how to fix it. The int I use just never updates, making the code useless... I use Visual Studio, windows fom app, if that changes something... Sorry for the lenght, but i don't know where's the problem. (Input 1 and 2 are textboxes...) The text file I use looks like this:
Username: *new line*
(costum text) *new line*
Password: *new line*
(costum text) *new line*
Username: *new line*
...

Here's the code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    //This is part of the problem

    int search = 0;

    //This is part of the problem (end)

    public void OK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string path = @"filePath.txt";
        var count = File.ReadLines(path).Count();
        string user = File.ReadLines(path).Skip(search + 1).Take(1).First();
        string pass = File.ReadLines(path).Skip(search + 3).Take(1).First();

        //Main problem

        if (Input1.Text != "" && Input2.Text != "")
        {
            while (Input1.Text == user && Input2.Text == pass)
        {
            if (search < count)
            {
                search = search + 4;
            }
                 
        }
            if (search < count)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("worked");
                search = 0;
            }
        }

        //Main problem (end)

    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Yes, you can fix it! But to help you get there, please read over [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question to 1. clarify what you are trying to do, and 2. [provide only relevant code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Is `public Form1()` relevant to this issue? Is `private void Save_Click()`? If not, please remove them from the question. From the looks of it, we'll also need to see some example input and the contents (or an example of the contents) of `Test.Save.txt`. Where are `UserText`/`PassText ` coming from?

Comment: Your code is written to go into an infinite loop, because you never change the value of your variables in your while condition.  To fix it, your code will need to change your code so that your variables can get changed so that the while condition can be made false.  If you want to be able to change UserText.Text, for example, then you need to stop the loop so that the program can get a changed value from UserText.Text.  While the code is looping, the GUI will be locked.

Comment: Hi Ray, looks like your while will lead to an infinite loop, since the values on the text will not change. Inside the while you should definitely keep reading user and pass variables if you ever want to break out of it (although keep in mind that would be very slow on a real life production code).

Comment: Ok. So if I add 4 to the int, which is used to search for lines, it will not change in the "while"? Or does the strings not change either?

Comment: I need a loop because i check lines in a text file, and the usernames and passwords are stored belove eachother. So i add 4 to the checked lines.

Comment: Okay - it would be good if you showed an example of the username/password file rather than just describing it.

Comment: Well, the file is not a part of the problem, and i have no idea how to show an understandable example.

Comment: Of course the file is part of the problem. The structure of the file is important to understand in order to write code that parses it properly. All you have to do is put an example of the file's structure in the question. About 10 lines worth should get the point across.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be greatly simplified. The usernames and passwords are on alternating lines, so they need to be declared inside of the loop. You can also use a for loop to control skipping to the next username/password combination at the end of each iteration of the loop. And you don't need to do File.ReadLines multiple times, that causes it to hit the disk multiple times for something you could just hold in memory once.

You should also rename your textboxes to have names that represent the data they should contain. So UsernameTextbox instead of Input1 for example.

```
public void OK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string path = @"filePath.txt";
    var fileLines = File.ReadLines(path);
    var authenticatedSuccessfully = false;
    
    for (int line = 0; line < fileLines.Length - 1; line += 2)
    {
        var user = fileLines[line];
        var password = fileLines[line + 1];
    
        if (UsernameTextbox.Text == user && PasswordTextBox.Text == pass)
        {
            authenticatedSuccessfully = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (authenticatedSuccessfully)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You are logged in!");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Incorrect username or password!");
    }
}
```

Of course...you should keep in mind that this is not secure at all. In the real world, passwords should be one way hashed and salted. Then when a user wants to authenticate you hash the password again and compare it to the stored value. If they match, then they provided the correct password. Storing passwords in plaintext is not a good idea.

Answer (score -1):

Your while condition is wrong. You can use for loop for that(using counters), or you need to rebuild your while loop. You must put if conditions inside While loop dont make them separate.  https://www.w3schools.com/cs/cs_while_loop.asp. Using while loop is good chance to go for infinite. So I am using For loops all the times.

Comment: For loops can also run infinitely long, just like while loops. If infinite looping isn't desired, the conditions must be structured so that there is a way out, or you can break out. Anyways, your "answer" here is really more of a comment - it doesn't do enough to address what should actually be done.

Comment: Ok, i changed the loop and now it works. At least it worked when i tryed.